# "gcloud app creat " needed permission?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I wanted to create an App Engine app using the following command

```
gcloud app create   --project=recommendations-1   --region=asia-east1-b
```

but system told me:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Operation not allowed
>
> - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo
>
>   description: The "appengine.applications.create" permission is
>     required.
>
>   resourceType: gae.api

Other information:

1. I use google cloud shell
2. before create app, I connect instance with [gcloud compute ssh recommendations-1 ]
3. I wanted to make recommendation system with (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/recommendation-system-tensorflow-deploy)
4. I have enabled [ App Engine Flexible Environment] and [App Engine Admin API] manually
5. I have gcloud auth login
6. I have gcloud config list project

Comment: you should have the permissions by default, if you have not messed around. Could you run `gcloud init`, and authenticate yourself again? Might work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have already created the project “recommendations-1”. If not, use this command first:

[gcloud projects create sample-project-name](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/create)

If yes, you can start by running the following commands:

[gcloud config set project sample-project-name](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set)

[gcloud app create --project=sample-project-name --region=valid-region](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/create)

Note that your command contains an invalid region. Check the valid regions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/regions/list) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations) or use this command to see the list and choose interactively on the console.

[gcloud app create](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations)

The issue you are having is most probably because you are trying to create an application in a project (recommendations-1) from within another project causing the permission errors.

You can have two machines running at the same time. As shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart#use_the_command_line) the VM that you access when using Cloud Shell is the active VM of the current project in the Cloud Console, so in case you access another VM with “gcloud compute ssh” in a terminal, you may be accessing different VMs. It will depend on which VM is set up on each tool.

So in case you are trying to create an app in the project “recommendations-1” using Cloud Shell, Cloud SDK or another tool, you will need to set "recommendations-1" as the current project in that tool by using the “gcloud config set project recommendations-1” command. If the Cloud Console current project is already set to "recommendations-1", Cloud Shell will automatically be set with this project.  Otherwise, you do not have access to create an app in a project from within the instance of another project.

Comment: one thing I always don't understand: when I open cloud shell I open one machine, but when I connect instance with gcloud compute ssh, I open another machine, that means I have two machines running at the same time ? But I can only create app with gcloud app engine at the first machine, but I don't have credential of the second one , so you said "The issue you are having is most probably because you are trying to create an application in a project (recommendations-1) from within another project causing the permission errors."